# $x_{n+1}=x_n\cos(y_n)-y_n\sin(y_n), y_{n+1}= x_n\sin(y_n)+y_n\cos(y_n) \implies \lim_{x \to \infty}x_n, \lim_{y \to \infty}y_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

**Question_**

> The sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are defined as $(x_1, y_1)=(0.8, 0.6)$,
>
> $x_{n+1}=x_n\cos(y_n)-y_n\sin(y_n)$ and
>
> $y_{n+1}= x_n\sin(y_n)+y_n\cos(y_n)$.
>
> Then, if $$\lim_{x \to \infty}x_n, \space\space\space \lim_{y \to \infty}y_n$$ exist, find the value of them. If they does not exist, prove it.

I'm not sure whether they have values or not. Here's the procedure I've made:

**My Own Procedure_**

> Let $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence given by $\tan\left(z_n\right)=y_n/x_n$.
>
> We can drive: 
>   $$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n^2+y_n^2}\cos(y_n+z_n)$$
>   $$y_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n^2+y_n^2}\sin(y_n+z_n)$$
>
> Using two equations, we can make a new equation about $y_n$ and $z_n$:
>   $$\tan(z_{n+1}) = \tan(y_n+z_n)$$
>   Subsequently,
>   $$z_{n+1} = y_n+z_n+k\pi$$

And I'm stuck here. Do you think that the procedure is going in the right way? Could you give me other key ideas about the problem? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x_0=y_0=0$, then $x_n=y_n=0$. Assume that $x_n^2+y_n^2>0$. Set
$$
x_n+iy_n=r_n\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta_n},
$$
then the recursion provides
$$
r_{n+1}\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta_{n+1}}=x_{n+1}+iy_{n+1}=\mathrm{e}^{iy_n}(x_{n}+iy_{n})=
r_n\mathrm{e}^{iy_n}\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta_n}
$$
Hence, $r_{n+1}=r_n=\cdots=r_0$, and
$$
\vartheta_{n+1}=\vartheta_n+y_n=\vartheta_n+r_0\sin \vartheta_n,
$$
modulo $2\pi$.

I have run a program and it does not always converge.

Convergence can be proved if $r_0<1/6$ and $\vartheta_0$ near $2k\pi$, in which case
$$
x_n\to r_0\quad\text{and}\quad y_n\to 0.
$$

Comment: When there's an equation $r_{n+1}e^{i\theta_{n+1}}=r_ne^{i(y_n+\theta_n)}$, can we sure that $r_{n+1}=r_n$ and $\theta_{n+1}=y_n+\theta_n$? I'm just confusing about the properties of polar forms. Sorry..!!

Comment: The $\vartheta_{n+1}=\vartheta_n+r_0\sin\vartheta_n$ is true modulo $2\pi$. Nevertheless, this is not so important, since we need to find $x_n,y_n$ and not $\vartheta_n$.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the last part - that you mentioned about $r_0<1/6$?

Comment: I think I now know what do the last part mean, through @Yves Daoust's answer. Thanks:D

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence converges, it will converge to a fixed point of 
$$G(x,y)=(x \cos y-y \sin y, x \sin y+y \cos y)$$

From the second equation, you can obtain $x = \frac{y(1-\cos y)}{\sin y}$, and substituting in the first equation you get
$$
\frac{y(1-\cos y)}{\sin y} (\cos y -1 )= y \sin y \Leftrightarrow -1 + 2 \cos y-\cos^2 y = 1- \cos ^2y \Leftrightarrow \cos y = 1
$$

So, assuming that $y\ne 0$ and $\sin y \ne 0$, we must have that $\cos y=1$, i.e. $y = 2 k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, which would mean that $\sin y = 0$... so, we can only have solutions if $y=0$ or $\sin y=0$.

If $y = 0$, $x$ can take any value. If $\sin y=0$, we must have $\cos y = 1$ and no restriction on $x$.

Bottom line: The points of the form $(x^*,2 k \pi), x^* \in \mathbb{R}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ are fixed points of $G$ and are therefore possible values for $\lim (x_n , y_n)$.

Depending on the initial "guess", the sequence may or may not converge, but when it converges, it will converge to one of these points. In the specific case of $(x_1,y_1)=(0.8, 0.6)$ the sequence converges to $(-1,0)$.

Comment: I've learned from you, especially the idea in the first part. Thanks!:D

Answer (score 1):

As shown by @Yiorgos, using the polar form the iterations are equivalent to

$$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_n+r\sin\theta_n,$$ with $r$ constant. With the given initial values, $r=1$, $\theta_1=\arctan\dfrac34$. Convergence is possible to a multiple of $\pi$, and by computing the first iterates, we do observe convergence to $\pi$.

Indeed, the function $\theta+\sin\theta$ is contractant around $\pi$ in the whole range $(0,2\pi)$, and the iterations will converge from $\theta_1$.

In fact, the function is asymptotically cubic around the fixed-point, and convergence is extremely fast.

[image]

$$0.6435011087933,\\1.2435011087933,\\2.1904164564551,\\3.0045155724143,\\3.1411637741144,\\3.1415926535766,\\\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful for me to understand the limits of $θ_{n+1}=θ_n+r\sin{θ_n}$.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to notice that the sum of the squares of the $2$ sequences is constant (i.e. $x_1^2+y_1^2$) here $x_n^2+y_n^2 = x_1^2+y_1^2 = 1$

Now,
$|x_{n+1}| = |x_n\cdot\cos(y_n) - y_n\cdot\sin(y_n)|$ , which is bounded above at $(x_n^2+y_n^2)^{1/2} = 1$
Also,
$x_{n+1} = x_n\cdot\cos((1-x_n^2)^{1/2}) - ((1-x_n^2)^{1/2})\cdot\sin(y_n) \le x_n - (1-x_n^2)^{1/2} < x_n$.
So by monotonic convergence theorem we can assert that $x_n$ is convergent

Similar arguments provide that , $|y_n| \le1$. Due to the nature of sine function when $y_n$ is less than $1$ we also conclude that $y_n$ is non-negative .
We also get that $y_n$ is increasing owing to the fact that $x_n$ is increasing and sum of the $2$ sequences is $1$ .
So we can again assert by monotone convergence theorem that $y_n$ converges .

Now passing over the lim gives $\lim y_n = 0$ and $\lim x_n^2=1$

Now notice that after a certain cutoff say $N$ belonging to set of Natural numbers $x_n$ is negative ($n>N$) so $\lim x_n < 0 \to \lim x_n = -1$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Leucippus Why do you think that does not provide an answer? can you explain?